# Woocommerce Reviews tab not showing on single product page

Tags: plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, review

On the website sagajackets.com, the Woocommerce Reviews tab is not visible on individual product pages. The website is currently using the Shoptimizer theme. To address this issue, the website owner has attempted various troubleshooting steps, including updating all themes and plugins, trying the 20twenty theme, and deactivating all plugins except for Woocommerce. Despite these efforts, the Reviews tab is still not showing on the product pages. Please refer to the attached image for reference.

[image]

Comment: Are reviews enabled under WooCommerce > Settings > Products?

Comment: you should ask this in a wooCommerce community, 3rd party themes/plugins are offtopic here

Comment: Hody_mcGee, Yes reviews are enabled, and also from setting discussions enable.